# Parse data from nested oci output with jq

Tags: jq, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How does one parse data from nested arrays using jq?  The path to the objects within the array I've not managed to decipher.  I'm a novice in this space and YouTube examples and the myriad of questions I've read and attempted to retool for my situation remains elusive.  Help appreciated.

The sanitized output from an oci command follows:

```
[
  {
    "agent-config": null,
    "availability-config": {
      "is-live-migration-preferred": null,
      "recovery-action": "RESTORE_INSTANCE"
    },
    "availability-domain": "AD",
    "capacity-reservation-id": null,
    "compartment-id": "ocid1.compartment.",
    "dedicated-vm-host-id": null,
    "defined-tags": {},
    "display-name": "TEST-VM",
    "extended-metadata": null,
    "fault-domain": "FAULT-DOMAIN",
    "freeform-tags": {},
    "id": "ocid1.instance.",
    "image-id": "ocid1.image.",
    "instance-options": {
      "are-legacy-imds-endpoints-disabled": false
    },
    "ipxe-script": null,
    "launch-mode": "PARAVIRTUALIZED",
    "launch-options": {
      "boot-volume-type": "PARAVIRTUALIZED",
      "firmware": "BIOS",
      "is-consistent-volume-naming-enabled": false,
      "is-pv-encryption-in-transit-enabled": false,
      "network-type": "PARAVIRTUALIZED",
      "remote-data-volume-type": "PARAVIRTUALIZED"
    },
    "lifecycle-state": "STOPPED",
    "metadata": {
      "ssh_authorized_keys": "lots_of_random"
    },
    "platform-config": null,
    "preemptible-instance-config": null,
    "region": "2nd-reg",
    "shape": "Standard1.1",
    "shape-config": {
      "baseline-ocpu-utilization": null,
      "gpu-description": null,
      "gpus": null,
      "local-disk-description": null,
      "local-disks": null,
      "local-disks-total-size-in-gbs": null,
      "max-vnic-attachments": 2,
      "memory-in-gbs": 16.0,
      "networking-bandwidth-in-gbps": 24.6,
      "ocpus": 1.0,
      "processor-description": null
    },
    "source-details": {
      "boot-volume-size-in-gbs": null,
      "boot-volume-vpus-per-gb": null,
      "image-id": "ocid1.image.",
      "kms-key-id": null,
      "source-type": "image"
    },
    "system-tags": null,
    "time-created": "2022-10-27T19:43:33.651460+00:00",
    "time-maintenance-reboot-due": null
  },
```

I'm looking for the display-name, id, memory-in-gbs.

I can gain the display-name and id with relative ease.
 `jq -r '.data[] |."display-name", ."id"'`

I can collect the memory-in-gbs as well with the following.
`jq -r '.data[] ."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"'`

I'm unable to get them together. The output from above will contain multiple iterations of the above data for each vm.  I'll use the data to build other queries, but I cant clear the first hurdle.

The end goal should look like this:
display-name
id
memory

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the structure you want them collected in using that structure's constructor, and assign the values to the desired places within the structure using the references you have used already.

Into an array, for example, using the [array constructor](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-construction) `[]`:

```bash
.data[] | [
  ."display-name",
  ."id",
  ."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"
]
```

```json
[
  "TEST-VM",
  "ocid1.instance.",
  16.0
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6M4IhB7HIDW)

Or into an object, using the [object constructor](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#object-construction) `{}`:

```bash
.data[]| {
  "display-name": ."display-name",
  "id": ."id",
  "memory": ."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"
}
```

```json
{
  "display-name": "TEST-VM",
  "id": "ocid1.instance.",
  "memory": 16.0
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OZX_7cJQAWv)

Both produce the structure in a sequence for each item within the `.data` array. If you want to collect them into an array, either wrap this in an outer array just as we did before:

```bash
[ .data[] | [ … ] ]
# or
[ .data[] | { … } ]
```

Or use the equivalent [`map`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#map-map_values) shortcut, which performs the iteration automatically (so you can strip `[]` from `.data`):

```bash
.data | map( [ … ] )
# or
.data | map( { … } )
```

Comment: Thank you, however I'm looking to print this to screen or redirect to a file for distribution so is there no way to harvest said data w/o re-creating a new object/array?  I hope to parse the ocid and use it in later queries but will use all the data collectively.

Comment: Of course there is. If you provide the exact sample output that you expect from the sample input given, I can update my answer to produce it. Please consider the case with more than one item in the `.data` array. In other words, what does the data look like that you want to use as input for the subsequent processing. For file redirection you would use the shell's redirection operator `>` as in `jq … input.json > output.json`

Comment: Understood.  So the sample data provided is the output from OCI (Oracle Cloud Infrastructure) and its piped to jq as follows:

`oci <insert subsequent commands> | jq -r '.data[] yada yada yada'  > report.txt`

Imagine the sample data being identical other than id and display-name.  

 output should resemble this:

Display Name: TEST-VM
ID: REALLYLONGID
Memory: 24GBs

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the necessary keys/names separated by a comma:

ie.:

```
jq -r '{name: .data[]."display-name", ocid: .data[]."id" }'
```

Comment: Using `.data[]` multiple times will iterate over the array items multiple times, creating a cartesian product.

Comment: So, this works w/ the exception of including quotes and braces.

`jq -r '{name: .data[]."display-name", ocid: .data[]."id", memory: .data[]."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"}'`

{
  "name": "test-vm",
  "ocid": "ocid1.instance.",
  "memory": 16.0
}

Comment: got ahead of myself...

So, this works w/ the exception of including quotes and braces and repeats over and over.  I guess the "cartesian product" @pmf mentioned. Darn close tho. 

`jq -r '{name: .data[]."display-name", ocid: .data[]."id", memory: .data[]."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"}'`

{
  "name": "test-vm",
  "ocid": "ocid1.instance.",
  "memory": 16.0
}

Comment: You can factor out the iteration by pulling it up front (`jq '.data[] | {name: ."display-name", ocid: ."id", memory: ."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs"}'`), but this is what I've provided you earlier. (With a JSON output, the `-r` flag has no effect.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jq 1.7 and don't care too much about the final structure of the result, you can use the `pick/1` function to pick the properties out from the items.

```
$ jq '.data[] | pick(."display-name", .id, ."shape-config"."memory-in-gbs")' input.json
{
  "display-name": "TEST-VM",
  "id": "ocid1.instance.",
  "shape-config": {
    "memory-in-gbs": 16.0
  }
}
```

Comment: That would be a great solution, however I'm stuck on 1.6.  Thanks though!